# For-each loop with a collection of class instances, multiple disposal warning

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

This code:

```
Private Sub assignButtons(ByVal Buttons As Collection, _
  ByVal ToolButton() As String, ByVal nToolButtons As Integer)

    For Each b As ToolStripItem In Buttons
      ... ' warning occurs even if these lines are commented out
    Next b
```

generates the following warning in VS Code Analysis:

> CA2202    Do not dispose objects multiple times
>   Object (*Buttons).GetEnumerator() can be disposed more than once in method
>   frmToolbar.assignButtons(ByRef Collection, ByRef String(), ByRef Integer). 
>   To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you
>   should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.

`Buttons` is a collection of ToolStripItems.

1. Is it a bad idea to iterate through a collection of class instances like this?
2. Are any of the instances disposed in this loop?

Comment: It is a false warning from CA.  Ignore or suppress it.  That seems like an odd place to get it though - usually it involves Using blocks.